# Android fragment transition callbacks

Tags: android-fragments, android

is there a way to detect that a fragment has started transition (in or out). What I am trying to acheve:

I have a fragment whcih has a SurfaceView with complex graphics in it. When I click on a button I want this fragment to slide away from the screen. But we all know, that SurfaceView can't be animated. So I want to replace it with a drawing cache bitmap before I start the transition.

There fore I need to know when the fragment starts transition. This is especially important for open transitions, because I call replace with image routine manually before out transition, but I need to know when the open transition was complete. Is there a better way than a timer (which seems awful to me).

Thanks.

P. S. compatibility lib

Comment: Did you solve your problem? I also need to know when fragment animation ends.

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head I'd say attach an animation listener to the animations you are using (see [Animation Listeners in the Android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html)) ..depending on your situation this might mean you need to create and attach the animations in code, or you may be able to retrieve the animation and attach the listener when you create the component (activity/fragment). It depends on how your current implementation works, but the basic idea is to attach a listener to the animation that is about to run. The animation listener will tell you when the animation actually starts and actually finishes..